# Finding object in ArrayList via user input - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to display `Car` from fleet `ArrayList` using user input. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to go about it. I have found few examples online but cannot make them work. I have incorporated following method:

```
 void findRegNo(String reg){
     boolean exist=false;
        for(int i=0;i<this.fleet.size();i++){
            if(this.fleet.get(i).getRegNo() == reg){
                exist=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(exist) {
            System.out.println("!!!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("xxx");
        }    
}
```

At the moment the result is always: xxx so the code does not find any match. That function is placed in my container class, I was thinking that maybe it supposed to be in different location.
These are variables of `Car` class:

```
public class Car {

    //defining variables
    String regNo;
    String model;
    double mileage;
```

Comment: Use `String.equals` to compare strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String`s are objects, not primitives. Hence, you should use `equals` to compare their **value**, not `==`, which checks that both references are to the same object:

```
if (this.fleet.get(i).getRegNo().equals(reg)) {
    exist = true;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, was struggling for a bit with it.